# Excel average if function for obtaining hourly data

Tags: excel-formula

I have minute data for air temperature and relative humidity (about 930,000 cells) for a building and I am trying to obtain the hourly average using excels "AverageIF" function. Here's the criteria that I have come up with:  **whenever one hour passes, average the air temperature and relative humidity for that hour.**  I am having trouble communicating these criteria to excel and any help would be appreciated. I have included a pic of what my data looks like:

[image: Example]

the yellow row is me manually adding a row after an hour has passed and calculated the average using the average function.

Comment: Just in case you are having difficulties adding a picture, small typed in example data is actually preferable.  We can copy and paste typed in date to our spreadsheet to help you where with a picture, a lot of people can wind up typing the same data.

Comment: This sounds very doable, but highly dependent on how your data is laid out.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

In the example above I went a bit long winded in the formula to deal with time intervals where there was no data, as that generates a divide by 0 error.

Essentially what I did was setup a summary table to the right.  I gave a start and end time for each hour (ASSUMING this is based on a 24 hour clock and not 1 hour from some arbitrary start time)

I used the AVERAGEIFS function as you have two criteria.  Everything after a start time and everything before an end time.  Only lines that match BOTH criteria are included.

The basic formula looks like this and is based on my example cell J4:

```
AVERAGEIFS(E$4:E$31,$C$4:$C$31,">="&$H4,$C$4:$C$31,"<="&$I4)
```

If the date is important, then you would need to add a date column to the table on the right and add a third criteria to the formula above.

In order to deal with divide by zero error and display blank instead of zero so you can distinguish between actual average of 0 and no data and still presenting an error when another type of error comes up I use the following formula in J4:

```
=IFERROR(AVERAGEIFS(E$4:E$31,$C$4:$C$31,">="&$H4,$C$4:$C$31,"<="&$I4),IF(ERROR.TYPE(AVERAGEIFS($E$4:$E$31,$C$4:$C$31,">="&$H4,$C$4:$C$31,"<="&$I4))=2,"","ERROR"))
```

The above formulas can be copied down and to the right.